# Конвертация валют и их отображение на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Получаю значения валют [c этого сайта](https://fixer.io). Нужно вывести котировки рубля к евро и рубля к доллару. Базовая валюта - евро, поэтому котировку рубля к доллару необходимо пересчитывать. Написал соответствующую функцию, с выводом котировки рубля проблем не возникло, а вот с долларом проблемы:

```
$(function () {
  $.get(
    "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest",
    { access_key: "402c715fe678630858fb57d485116c" },

    function (response) {
      $(".currencies-value-eur").text(response.rates.RUB);
      console.log(response.rates.USD);
      let eur = $(".currencies-value-eur").val();
      let usd = $(response.rates.USD).val();
      $(".currencies-value-usd").text(usd / eur);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: В чем именно проблемы?

Comment: Выводится "NaN", не получается вывести курс доллара к рублю

Comment: Ошибка в строке `let usd = $(response.rates.USD).val();`. Сравните со строкой выше, евро.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш комментарий помог сделать то что нужно. Ниже выложу пример кода, который позволяет вывести на сайте курсы валют через API-запрос, а также сделать конвертацию любой валюты (у меня рубль к доллару), если она не доступна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
//подключаемся к источнику данных:
$.get('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest', {'access_key': '402c715fe678630858ff1b57d485116c'},

function(response) {
 //получаем котировки нужных валют:   
$('.currencies-value-eur').val(response.rates.RUB);
$('.currencies-value-usd').val(response.rates.USD);
    //объявляем переменные:
    let eur = $('.currencies-value-eur').val();
    let usd = $('.currencies-value-usd').val();
        //конвертируем нужную валюту относительно базовой и выводим на свой сайт:
        $('.currencies-value-usd').text(eur / usd);
        $('.currencies-value-eur').text(response.rates.RUB);
});
```

});